# Logging into tumblr with jsoup

Tags: java, cookies, authentication, jsoup, tumblr

I'm trying to log into tumblr using jsoup. I've searched some similar questions and they said a similar code doesn't work because it's missing a `sessionid`. Then, I typed `javascript:void(alert(document.cookie))` to try to get one, but I didn't see any `sessionid` parameters. I'm using the following code:

```
try {
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.tumblr.com/login")
        .data("signup_email", "myemail@yahoo.com", "signup_password", "mypassword")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

        //sessionId = res.cookie("SESSIONID");
        cookiesoup = res.cookies();
} catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This code didn't work", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Why not use the official API?

Comment: The API has many limitations on the amount of posts it can load etc. so it's not useful for doing what I need it to do. I already have most of my other code in jsoup anyways.

Comment: Can you post the contents of res.cookies()?

Answer (score 0):

```
private String login_url = "https://www.tumblr.com/login";
private String bblog_url = "https://www.tumblr.com/services/bblog";
private String user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36";
private String email;
private String password;

//connect to Tumblr Login Page
Response login_page = Jsoup.connect(login_url).method(Method.GET).execute();

Document login_document = login_page.parse();

//get hidden tokens needed to login
String random_username_suggestions = Jsoup.parse(login_document.select("input[name=random_username_suggestions]").attr("value")).text();
String form_key = login_document.select("input[name=form_key]").attr("value");

Map<String, String> login_page_cookies = login_page.cookies();

//POST request to bblog url needed for login
Jsoup
.connect(bblog_url)
.cookies(login_page_cookies)
.referrer(login_url)
.ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true)
.userAgent(user_agent)
.method(Method.POST)
.execute();

//Finally request to login page with required form data
Response login_response = Jsoup.connect(login_url)
        .data("determine_email", email)
        .data("user[email]",email)
        .data("user[password]",password)
        .data("tumblelog[name]","")
        .data("user[age]","")
        .data("context","other")
        .data("version","STANDARD")
        .data("follow","")
        .data("http_referer","https://www.tumblr.com/logout")
        .data("form_key", form_key)
        .data("seen_suggestion","0")
        .data("used_suggestion","0")
        .data("used_auto_suggestion","0")
        .data("about_tumblr_slide","")
        .data("random_username_suggestions", random_username_suggestions)
        .cookies(login_page_cookies)
        .userAgent(user_agent)
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

Document login_reponse_document = login_response.parse();

String user_id = login_reponse_document.select("input[name=t]").attr("value");

// This will print current username
System.out.println(user_id);
```